# How to filter String data using search list in Google sheets/Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I want to filter addresses (column A) if they contain any city name from city list (column B). Here is how data looks like:

| Adresses (Col A) | Cities (Col B) |
| --- | --- |
| 900 Rancho Diego Pkwy, Buellton, CA 92028 | Ventura |
| 3850, Toepperwein Rd, Antonio, TX 78264 | San Antonio |
| 3250 El Camino Real, Atascadero, CA 93444 | Buellton |
| 2340 Palma Dr, Ventura, CA 93090 | New York |
| Valley Rd, Santa Maria, CA 93420 |  |

In the above table, only 2 cities `(Ventura, Buellton)` in column B are found in Addresses in Column A, so the output should be:

> 900 Rancho Diego Pkwy, Buellton, CA 92019
>
> 2340 Palma Dr, Ventura, CA 93003

I tried following formulas but to no effect:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, REGEXMATCH(A2:A, B2:B))
=FILTER(A2:A, MATCH(A2:A, B2:B,0))
=FILTER(A2:A, COUNTIF(B2:B, A2:A))
```

How to compile list of addresses (Col A) if any city name (Col B) is found in the address? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

withing GSheets please try:

**UPDATED FORMULA:**

- this strictly extracts the cities names within the address to tally against the list in Column B to avoid random mismatches.

`=FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,IFNA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(ax,", ([^,]*), [A-Z]{2}"),REGEXEXTRACT(ax,", ([^,]*), [^,]*$")))))),"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,B2:B)))`

Comment: Can you please explain why are we using `"(?i)"` in formula?

Comment: updated the formula since I see that casual regex is matching city `List` with an address like `100 Hollister Rd` and `(?i)` keeps a check on case insensitivity.

Comment: ok, your updated formula output less entries than your previous formula

Comment: yes it should. you can test part of the formula separately `=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(ax,IF(ax="",,IFNA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(ax,", ([^,]*), [A-Z]{2}"),REGEXEXTRACT(ax,", ([^,]*), [^,]*$"))))))` and see how the city names are extracted from full address & then used to match them with Column B list.

Comment: in this `900 Rancho San Diego Pkwy, El Cajon, CA 92019` formula pulled `El Cajon`, sorry for my poor knowledge, isn't `San Diego` a city?

Comment: if you wish to match anywhere in the address line then you can just use: `=FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"(?i)\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b",1,B2:B)&"\b"))`

Comment: `=FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"(?i)\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b",1,B2:B)&"\b"))` when I put this formula, column B was empty and it still outputs entries

Comment: try: `=FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,"(?i)\b"&TEXTJOIN("\b|\b",1,B2:B)&"\b")*COUNTA(B2:B)<>0)`

Comment: Can we add state with the city as well, for example it would search for `Ventura, CA` instead of `Ventura`

Answer (score 2):

Use `FILTER()` with `MMULT()` in `Excel`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=FILTER(B3:B7,MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(C3:C6),B3:B7))),ROW(C3:C6)^0))
```

---

Works in `Google-Sheets` as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=FILTER(B3:B7, MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(C3:C6),B3:B7))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(C3:C6),1,1,0)))
```

---

An alternative approach using `BYROW()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=FILTER(B3:B7,BYROW(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TOROW(C3:C6),B3:B7))),LAMBDA(m,SUM(m))))
```

---

For `Google-Sheets` replace the `TOROW()` with `TRANSPOSE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=FILTER(B3:B7,BYROW(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(C3:C6),B3:B7))),LAMBDA(m,SUM(m))))
```

---

Instead of taking all the rows it is better to use `Table Structured References`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=LET(_cityName,FILTER(C3:C1048576,C3:C1048576<>""),
_addresses,FILTER(B3:B1048576,B3:B1048576<>""),
FILTER(_addresses,MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(_cityName),_addresses))),SEQUENCE(ROWS(_cityName)))))
```

---

With `BYROW()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=LET(_cityName,FILTER(C3:C1048576,C3:C1048576<>""),
_addresses,FILTER(B3:B1048576,B3:B1048576<>""),
_searchArray,N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TOROW(_cityName),_addresses))),
FILTER(_addresses,BYROW(_searchArray,LAMBDA(m,SUM(m)))))
```

---

Or, create a **Defined Name** in **Name Manager** with the `LAMBDA()` formula and use the range as per your need.

[image]

---

**Refers To:**

```
=LAMBDA(Cities,Addresses,
LET(_cityName,FILTER(Cities,Cities<>""),
_addresses,FILTER(Addresses,Addresses<>""),
_searchArray,N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TOROW(_cityName),_addresses))),
FILTER(_addresses,BYROW(_searchArray,LAMBDA(m,SUM(m))))))(C3:C1048576,B3:B1048576)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `E3`

```
=LISTDATA(C3:C1048576,B3:B1048576)
```

---

In `Google-Sheets`

[image]

---

```
=FILTER(B3:B,BYROW(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C3:C,C3:C<>"")),B3:B))),LAMBDA(m,SUM(m))))
```

---

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however when I delete any `city name` from column C or make the formula generic like converting `B3:B7,C3:C7` to `B3:B,C3:C`, it output all addresses.

Comment: This is `B3:B,C3:C` basically for `Google-Sheets` not for `Excel`

Comment: @EagleEye try this : `=FILTER(B3:B,BYROW(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C3:C,C3:C<>"")),B3:B))),LAMBDA(m,SUM(m))))`

Comment: when I put your formula in google sheet, it says `Unknown function: 'LET'`

Comment: The comment above yours work with `G-Sheet` `LET()` is not available in `Google-Sheet` since you have mentioned both kind of spreadsheet i have given all the options

Comment: ok, thank you, I am trying this now: `=FILTER(B3:B,BYROW(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(C3:C,C3:C<>"")),B3:B))),LAMBDA(m,SUM(m))))`

Comment: Here is a link: [Google-Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1euN2Y5b5gC5SxWIYflPorZzpKAQvzvH8x1gYgAJ1thw/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you please review it and point out the error, I followed your instructions:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OU9eWDRbEhsOP0rj-wHdLtQe5uCsaTydBD_zN22jjHI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @EagleEye it is not working because I have used `TRANSPOSE()` function, and you have search values more than 300 where as the number of columns are less that that

Answer (score 1):

You were close with this

```
=FILTER(A2:A, REGEXMATCH(A2:A, B2:B))
```

The second argument of `REGEXMATCH` shouldn't be a range though, this will work:

```
=FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,TEXTJOIN("|",1,B2:B)))
```

Comment: yeah, I tried it. The only issue with it is if I delete any city, it outputs all addresses

Comment: you've probably used JOIN, I used TEXTJOIN and intentionally set the 2nd parameter to 1 to avoid this.

Comment: it outputs the addesses even if there is no value (city) in column B

Comment: can you share a link to the sheet?

Comment: No issue, I have modified it to `=FILTER(A2:A,REGEXMATCH(A2:A,TEXTJOIN("|",1,B2:B)),B2:B<>"")`

Can we add state with the city as well, for example it would search for `Ventura, CA` instead of `Ventura`